# Ubuntu 16.10 bar objects not opening

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 16.10

Since upgrading there is an annoying behaviour which sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't. On the top of the screen there are icons for skype, language choice etc. I am used to that when I bring the cursor over one of these, down comes a menu and I can choose what to do.

With 16.10 it happens (and is currently happening) that the cursor just sits on the icon and nothing happens. I am not aware of what causes this. Usually I can reboot to fix the problem, until it happens again.

Just now I upgraded Virutalbox running Windows, and I see on the view menu of virtualbox that I can do nothing, where I can normally use full screen for example. So the problem shows up in virtualbox as well.

I'm sorry that I can't put my finger on what causes the problem. Has anyone else seen such a thing and are there any suggestions on what can be done to fix it?

Thanks,
Ilan

P.S. I noticed that one of my cores was at 100% approximately 80% of the time. I looked at the processes and the unity-panel-service was taking the most CPU time.

This starts to make sense. Something is causing the unity-panel-service to go into saturation, so that it has no time to respond to my requests. The question is if I can figure out which program is demanding all the time from the unity-panel-service. It sounds like a bug in that some program is able to make excessive demands and that unity allows the program to get away with it.

Perhaps there is a log file somewhere which will give a hint as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When the problem occurred I turned off one service after another.
Finally I turned off owncloud and unity-panel-service came back to life.

Apparently this is a know issue:
https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4985